# Android: when can I save the data, if the service quitting by system

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, storage

I have to save the a location state of the view added on the windowmanager.  I thought of using SharedPreference to save the data and put inside the onDestroy method provided by the Service. I search other sites, many people said sometime onDestroy would not get called by the system. If stored the data when the view moved, will that give heavy load to system to read/write the SharedPreference

Comment: Store the location immediately when it changes. Don't worry about performance - that's what's called premature optimization. Use `apply()` to commit the changes to your `SharedPreferences` instance.

Comment: What about the commit... when to use commit

Comment: `apply()` and `commit()` do the same thing, but the difference is that `apply()` saves the changes asynchronously in the background and `commit() ` does it synchronously. You always want to use `apply()`.  In fact Android Studio should warn you every time you use `commit()` and offer a quick fix to swap it out with `apply()`.

Comment: So to answer your question more directly: Never use `commit()`.

Comment: Thank for your advice